# ERR_PNPM_ERR_PNPM_UNEXPECTED_PKG_CONTENT_IN_STORE The lockfile is broken! A full installation will be performed in an attempt to fix it

Tags: pnpm

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wj6r.png)

ERR_PNPM_ERR_PNPM_UNEXPECTED_PKG_CONTENT_IN_STORE

Answer (score 4):

There was an edge case in an older version of pnpm (I don't remember exactly which, probably pre v6.30), where the store got corrupted. So I would suggest to

1. upgrade pnpm to the latest version
2. remove the store (to get the store location, run `pnpm store path`)
3. run `pnpm install`

If the lockfile is changed, it means the lockfile was broken, so commit the changed lockfile.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem not long ago on pnpm@8.x.

I finally solved it via `rm -rf $(pnpm store path)`.